# Java design issues with enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a class which has different variables , and User defined Enum is also one of them.
This Class basially represents the data in a table.

eg)

```
Class A {

   private String x;
   private String y;
   private UserEnum z;
   ....
   ..

  private UserEnum getField() {
     ....
  }   

  private void addRow() {
  // uses the UserEnum here
      ....        
  }
```

}

I have an other class (CLASS B) which does the same functionality as the class A(has the same methods and fields) except that I have a different user defined enum (eg. UserEnum2).
Both these Enums has different set of constants.

What would be the good design to avoid the duplicate code which exists in both these classes.
I am new to Enums and I am not sure how we can really generalize the above mentioned two classes(CLASS A and CLASS B) which has different Enums.

Answer (score 2):

Create a base class with the commons fields and methos, then create sub-classes with the rest of fields and methods/

```
Class abstract Base {

   private String x;
   private String y;
   ....
   ..

  private UserEnum getField() {
     ....
  }   

  private abstract void addRow();
}

class A extends Base{
    private UserEnum z;
    ...
}

class B extends Base{
    private UserEnum2 z;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with a tool some time ago. The way I dealt with it was to have a base class that was generic:

```
public class Table<Column extends Enum<Column> & Table.Columns> {

    public interface Columns {
    }
```

the subclasses look something like:

```
public class VersionTable extends Table<VersionTable.Column> {

  public enum Column implements Table.Columns {

    Version,
    Alias;

  }
```

they register their specific `enum` through a `super(Columns)` constructor.

Obviously there is much more to this than I can post in an answer but rest assured it is possible to have a completely type-safe mechanism using this structure.

Comment: I kind of like this idea. Basically you are trying to create the Generic Table with different Enum types(columns) .. I was looking for a similar solution  ,  but was not sure how it can be done with Enum Types. Thanks!!

Comment: @dsreddy - the elegance of this technique is that you get type safety **and** enums.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation.  Delegate the duplicated methods to a single delegate class, and all 3 of the classes (the 2 enums and the delegates) all implement the interface for those duplicated methods.